# Why getting wrong results when performing pointer arithmetic in C on dynamically linked symbols?

Tags: c, function-pointers, dynamic-linking, linux-toolchain, avr32

I encountered a weird situation where performing pointer arithmetic involving
dynamically linked symbols leads to incorrect results. I'm unsure if there 
are simply missing some linker parameters or if it's a linker bug. Can someone
explain what's wrong in the following example?

Consider the following code (`lib.c`) of a simple shared library:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uintptr_t getmask()
{
  return 0xffffffff;
}

int fn1() 
{
  return 42;
}

void fn2() 
{
  uintptr_t mask; 
  uintptr_t p;

  mask = getmask();
  p = (uintptr_t)fn1 & mask; 
  printf("mask: %08x\n", mask);
  printf("fn1:  %p\n",   fn1); 
  printf("p:    %08x\n", p);
}
```

The operation in question is the bitwise AND between the address of `fn1` and
the variable `mask`. The application (`app.c`) just calls `fn2` like that:

```
extern int fn2();

int main()
{
  fn2();

  return 0;
}
```

It leads to the following output ...

```
mask: ffffffff
fn1:  0x2aab43c0
p:    000003c0
```

... which is obviously incorrect, because the same result is expected for `fn1`
and `p`. The code runs on an AVR32 architecture and is compiled as follows:

```
$ avr32-linux-uclibc-gcc -Os -Wextra -Wall -c -o lib.o lib.c
$ avr32-linux-uclibc-gcc -Os -Wextra -Wall -shared -o libfoo.so lib.o
$ avr32-linux-uclibc-gcc -Os -Wextra -Wall -o app app.c -L. -lfoo
```

The compiler thinks, it is the optimal solution to load the variable
`mask` into 32 bit register 7 and splitting the &-operation into two assembler
operations with immediate operands.

```
$ avr32-linux-uclibc-objdump -d libfoo.so

000003ce <fn1>:
 3ce:   32 ac           mov     r12,42
 3d0:   5e fc           retal   r12

000003d2 <fn2>:
 ...
 3f0:   e4 17 00 00     andh    r7,0x0
 3f4:   e0 17 03 ce     andl    r7,0x3ce
```

I assume the immediate operands of the `and` instructions are not relocated
to the loading address of `fn1` when the shared library is loaded into the
applications address space:

- Is this behaviour intentional?
- How can I investigate whether problem occurs when linking the shared library or when loading the executable?

*Background:* This is not an academic questions. OpenSSL and LibreSSL
use similar code, so changing the C source is not an option. The code runs
well on other architectures and certainly there is an unapparent reason for
doing bitwise operations on function pointers.

Comment: `return 0xffffffff` -> `return ~(uintptr_t )0` ?

Comment: What would `print(" fn1-x : %08x\n", (uintptr_t) fn1);` give?

Comment: What do you get if you compile without optimizations?

Comment: @Bathsheba why would `return 0xffffffff` be different from `return ~(uintptr_t)0` on a 32 bit environnment?

Comment: You seem to be missing -fPIC when compiling lib.c (I'm surprised you didn't get a warning from compiler). Also format argument for p is wrong (I suggest to use %llx and cast to long long to avoid messing with inttypes.h).

Comment: `uintptr_t` is only defined for object pointers, not function pointers. Function pointers can not be cast to any other pointer type, including void. So your code is undefined behavior. Especially function pointers into shared libraries will not behave the way you expect them to because of how relocation is done.

Comment: @Art `uintptr_t` is an integer, not a pointer. Function pointers may be converted to integers.. 6.3.2.3/6: "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type."

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What happens if you change to `printf("p:    %08" PRIuPTR "\n", p);`?

Comment: @yugr: The shared objects files are binary equal no matter whether using -fPIC or not. I think the compiler produces PIC by default.

Comment: @Lundin: Same result as above with `PRIuPTR`. The output will be merely decimal, but the value is the same. Have you tried on an AVR32 architecture? Which compiler and binutils do you use? On Intel the code works fine, since the relocation process is instruction-set dependant.

Comment: Nope I tried on a 32 bit ARM with gcc. I suppose there is something fishy with your compiler port.

Comment: @Michael Walz: Without size-optimization the code works as expected in this simple case. But I encountered this problem in LibreSSL. Recompiling with changed compiler settings doesn't solve the problem there. If you are interested, the code in question is located in line 933 of this file https://github.com/libressl-portable/openbsd/blob/84ca37c024bbc9197512e41eaf0136ae0cefbc1a/src/lib/libcrypto/bn/bn_nist.c

Comment: `fn` is a function pointer, so you should cast it to `(void*)` before passing to `%p`

Comment: All of your `printf` statements cause undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier. So the output is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

after correcting all the 'slopiness' in the code, the result is:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fn1( void );
void fn2( void );
uintptr_t getmask( void );

int main( void )
{
  fn2();

  return 0;
}

uintptr_t getmask()
{
  return 0xffffffff;
}

int fn1() 
{
  return 42;
}

void fn2() 
{
  uintptr_t mask; 
  uintptr_t p;

  mask = getmask();
  p = (uintptr_t)fn1 & mask; 
  printf("mask: %08x\n", (unsigned int)mask);
  printf("fn1:  %p\n",   fn1); 
  printf("p:    %08x\n", (unsigned int)p);
}
```

and the output (on my linux 64bit computer) is:

```
mask: ffffffff
fn1:  0x4007c1
p:    004007c1
```

Comment: The `%p` format specifier must take a `void *` argument

Comment: @M.M: otherwise it results in UB.

Comment: Since any pointer can be used as a `void*` in a parameter list, the compiler will not complain about the statement: `printf("fn1:  %p\n",   fn1);` and will produce the correct result.